# ¿Cómo puedo hacer en un día préstamo?

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-forms

Estoy realizando una aplicación en Windows Forms que administra el préstamo de equipos y herramientas, para cada préstamo se deben agregar los productos a prestar, entonces, ¿Cómo se podría hacer para agregar los productos al detalla del préstamo al momento de registrar el préstamo?

Este es el módelado de la tabla préstamo y cómo está relacionada.

[image: Este es el modelo de la tabla préstamo con sus relaciones]

Comment: como accedes a los datos? usas ado.net o entity framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta seria un poco larga, pero tengo un articulo que podria dar una pista

[[N-Tier] – Desarrollo en capas - Ejemplo Facturación – Parte 3](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2010/08/n-tier-desarrollo-en-capas-ejemplo.html)

analiza como se implementa `InvoiceDAL.Create()` alli persisto usando ado.net la factura y su detalle, enviando en una sola entidad de `invoice` todo lo necesario

Se realiza el insert de la factura

```
string sqlFactura = @"INSERT INTO Invoice (CustomerId, InvoiceDate, BillingAddress, Total) VALUES (@customerId, @date, @address, @total)
           SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlFactura, conn))
{

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerId", invoice.CustomerId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", invoice.InvoiceDate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", invoice.BillingAddress);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", 0);

    invoice.InvoiceId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

y luego usanfo el invoce id se registran los detalles

```
string sqlLineaFactura = @"INSERT INTO InvoiceLine (InvoiceId, TrackId, UnitPrice, Quantity) 
                            VALUES (@invoiceid, @trackid, @unitprice, @quantity)
                            SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlLineaFactura, conn))
{

    foreach (InvoiceLinesEntity invoiceLine in invoice.Lineas)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoiceid", invoice.InvoiceId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trackid", invoiceLine.TrackId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unitprice", invoiceLine.UnitPrice);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", invoiceLine.Quantity);

        invoiceLine.InvoiceLineId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿De qué manera obtienes los datos que van dentro del método?, revisando en unos cuantos artículos, me sugieren utilizar un datagriedview e ir llenandolo con los datos de los productos que tengo en la base de datos (consultando llos productos en otra pantalla), pero no estoy seguro de si hay otra forma.

Comment: pero el tema es obtener o persistir? si vas a mostrar esta claro que un solo grid no alcanza, salvo que este permite desplegar el detalle, pero el control datagridview estandar no lo permite. Podrias usar dos grid, entonces en un listas los prestamos y la ir seleccionando en otro grid muestras el detalle